# Wordpress plugin Blog Update Reminder only works for administrators

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a wordpress site with one post where users can write a comment everyday.
I have installed the plugin Blog Update Reminder because I would like users to receive a daily reminder.
My problem is, that the plugin can only see administrators, not authors or participants. And giving users the administrator role is not an option.

For administration of the users and the logins, I have the plugin Ultimate Member.

I have never worked with wordpress or php before and I don't know where the problem can be?

I hope that somebody can help me, because I am very frustrated about this.

Comment: After a lot of pondering I am now a bit wiser regarding my question. The problem was not that Blog Update Reminder only would work with administrators as I first thought. And Ultimate Member also didn't cause any problems.

But Blog Update Reminder only lists authors of posts, not authors of comments. The only two administrators on my site were also the only two authors of posts - hence my confusion. I wanted a plugin, that could remind comment authors to write a comment and BUR does not have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider using another plugin? The one you are using seems to be only for admin notification. Maybe this could provide you with the functionality you want;

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/

Comment: Hi Dennis.Thank you for your quick answer. Bnfw does not have the functionality I seek. I also tried it and bought the Update Reminder Add on. It can only remind authors of a post to update the post. It cannot remind authors of a comment to update the comment.

Comment: This is from the readme file: Blog Update Reminder is designed to remind a Wordpress blog's author(s) with an email if they haven't made a blog post in a set number of days. When this plugin is installed, it automatically finds all authors (users) of the blog, and sets their "interval of days" to zero. The list of authors in Blog Update Reminder's settings will automatically update with the addition or removal of Wordpress blog users. The list of users and their set "interval of days" can be viewed from Blog Update Reminder's settings panel, found under the Wordpress "Settings" menu.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood what was the problem, I'm sorry!

It seems the Ultimate Member saves it's users as "um_user", instead of as a true Wordpress user and this could be causing the issue. You could rewrite the Blog Reminder plugin to query "um_users" from the $wpdb query, but this will break when/if the Blog Reminder plugin is updated.

In blogreminder.php file the "get_blogusers()" could be altered to query from Ultimate Member's table and get their users instead of WP's.

Comment: Hi Dennis Thank you for your interest. I tried changing the query from "users" to "um_users" but I cannot get it to work. I have added the codesnippet in the plugin that seems to fetch the users. If you easily can see, how it should be done, I would be very grateful..

Comment: // Get list of blog users with timestamps from wordpress database
function get_blogusers() {
 global $wpdb;
 $blogusers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT u.ID, u.user_nicename, u.display_name, u.user_email, p.post_date FROM $wpdb->users u INNER JOIN (SELECT post_author, MAX(post_date) post_date FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_title != 'Auto Draft' AND post_title != '' GROUP BY post_author) p WHERE u.ID = p.post_author ORDER BY u.display_name");
 return $blogusers;
}